# Why don't Donetsk and Luhansk unite?

Tags: ukraine, secession

Considering they are both populated by ethnic Russians and have a common enemy, why don't Donetsk and Luhansk unite in a single political entity (state)? What are the distinctions between their separate identities, essentially differences between the two?